# HTC One X - shows "compatibility" menu icon

Tags: android, android-support-library, htc-android

I have application which uses Sherlock ActionBar package.

The application uses platform-specific behavior for menu (so it's 3-dot icon in ActionBar on ICS and classic menu under HW button on pre-ICS)

I had recieved report from one user with HTC One X. It appears, that One X shows some "compatibility" bar with menu button on the bottom of screen, and there is also same button in ActionBar (where it's supposed to be).

I was not able to emulate this in AVD, and I have multiple reports that this issue is not present on Galaxy Nexus or Galaxy S (they show only the icon in ActionBar).

I have no idea where to look to resolve this or how to debug it, so any help or workaround will be appreciated.

Application is built against API14, with targetSdk="11"

Comment: Hmmmm I think this is a special case because HTC did something wierd with the One X and they took out only the menu button (instead of taking out all of them, like the Galaxy Nexus). Have you tried creating an AVD with everything *but* the menu button?

Comment: Blah, I just checked and the only option is "Hardware Back/home keys", which I guess it's just everything.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have a typo:

The [`android:targetSdkVersion`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#target) in the manifest should be the solution - it's recommended by Google to always set it to the maximum available (currently it's 19).

Some websites do show that HTC shows the huge button on old apps, but not on new ones, as shown [here](http://www.androidcentral.com/htc-one-x-shows-us-why-developers-need-lose-menu-button), so if you think it's weird/ugly, simply set the target [SDK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_development_kit). Also make sure it's updated in the `project.properties` file .

Comment: It was only typo in the post here, not in AndroidManifest.xml.
Anyway, setting targetSdkVersion to 15 worked, thank you!